# Time Conversion to 24 hour format cpp

Tags: c++

I am stuck with this program can anyone please help in converting the 12 hour format to 24 hour format?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

string timeConversion(string s) {
// Complete this function
string d,c;
d=s.substr(8,2);
if(d=="PM"){
int a;
a=stoi(s.substr(0,2));
a=a+12;
c=to_string(a);
}
s[0]=c[0];
s[1]=c[1];
s=s.substr(0,8);
return s;
}
int main() {
string s;
cin >> s;
string result = timeConversion(s);
cout << result << endl;
return 0;
}

Sample Input: 7:05:45PM

Sample Output: 19:05:45
```

Now i had edited my code and it is running but can you tell  me better ways to do this code??

Comment: Please describe how you are stuck

Comment: Have you tried converting `a` (the hour token) to an integer, parsing `d` and comparing it to `"PM"`, and possibly adding 12 to the `a` integer, and then reforming the date from the resulting `a`, `b` and `c`?

Comment: @NathanOliver i want to  change the first two  letters of string but unable to convert string to number and also want to remove last two letters of string

Comment: Have you look up how to convert a string to a number?  There is plenty of answers on how to do that.  You could also just do the operation manually yourself.

Answer (score 4):

```
string timeConversion(string s)
{
   string hour = s.substr(0,2);
   string id = s.substr(8,2);
   int iHour = stoi(hour.c_str());

   if( id == "PM" )
   {
       if( iHour != 12 )
           iHour += 12;

       hour = to_string(iHour);
   }

   if( id == "AM" )
   {
       if( iHour == 12 )
           hour = "00";
       else if( iHour < 10 )
           hour = "0" + to_string(iHour);
       else
           hour = to_string(iHour);
   }

   return hour + s.substr(2,6);
}
```

This works for me and passes all 9 test cases on the HackerRank website.

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to do this but I am going to use the code you made.

**Note:** I removed the `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` library

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

string timeConversion(string s) 
{
    string a = s.substr(0,2); //hours
    string b = s.substr(3,2); //minutes
    string c = s.substr(6,2); //seconds
    string d = s.substr(8,2); //AM or PM
    int hours = atoi(a.c_str());
    if (d == "PM")
        hours += 12; //If it is PM just add 12 hours to the time

    string temp;
    if (hours == 0)
       temp = "00";
    else 
       temp = to_string(hours);        
    temp += ":" + b + ":" + c; //concat the strings

    return temp ;
}

int main() 
{
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    string result = timeConversion(s);
    cout << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i am setting a=00 but it is displaying a=0 only how to solve this problem?

Comment: Understand how I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the most beginner friendly c++ way.

```
#include<sstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

string timeConversion(string s) {
        istringstream is(s);
        int hours;
        int minutes;
        int seconds;
        string ampm;
        char colon;
        is >> hours >> colon >> minutes >> colon >> seconds >> ampm;
        if(is.fail()) {
                return "Error: wrong format";
        }
        ostringstream os;
        if(ampm == "PM") {
                hours += 12;
        }
        os 
        << setfill('0') << setw(2)
        << hours << ':' 
        << setfill('0') << setw(2)
        << minutes << ':' 
        << setfill('0') << setw(2)
        << seconds;
        return os.str();
}

int main() {
        string s = "7:05:05PM";
        cout << timeConversion(s) << '\n';
        return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- `istringstream` and `ostringstream` are similar to `cin` and `cout` but operate on string instead of input/output.
- `<< setfill('0') << setw(2)` -> this part makes it print `07` instead of 7 if any of hours minutes or seconds has only one digit
- I have not handled valid edge cases like 12:00:01PM or 12:00:01AM.
- I have also not done error conditions where the input format is correct but data is wrong for e.g minutes should not be above 60.

I think you can improve for those cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
string timeConversion(string s) {

     string ntime;
     string h = s.substr(0,2);
     int hh= stoi(h);
     if(s[8] == 'P')
     {
    
         if(hh != 12 )
         {

               hh = hh + 12;
               ntime = to_string(hh);
         }
         else if (hh == 12)
         {
               ntime = to_string(hh);
         }
     }
     else if(s[8] == 'A')
         {

               if(hh == 12){
               ntime = "00";
          }      
          else
          {
                 ntime = s.substr(0,2);
          }
    
     }
     string military = ntime+":"+s.substr(3,5);
     return military;

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).